# How to create fixed digit crypto key using Node.js Crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to this, but my requirement is that I want 20 characters long crypto key using Node.js Crypto module.

I tried but could not get fixed length key.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The example at https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher shows a working example and indicates key length is dependant on algorithm. I expect an undersized key might be padded though. Why do you need 20 exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [crypto.randomBytes](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) to generate keys, for example:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = crypto.randomBytes(10).toString('hex');
console.log(`key: ${key} length: ${key.length}`);
```

You can also use the [crypto.scrypt](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_scryptsync_password_salt_keylen_options) function to derive a fixed-length key from a longer passphrase:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const key = crypto.scryptSync('my secret pass phrase', 'my salt', 10).toString('hex');
console.log(`key: ${key} length: ${key.length}`);
```